# Request.Form as array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Greetings. I have some inputs dynamically added to form.

```
<input name="input_names[]" />
```

When form was posted, I can get these names like this:

```
var names = Request.Form["input_names[]"];
```

And I've got CSV string. It's not a problem and I can split it by comma. Problem happens when I write down text which includes comma. Then I cannot split this string correctly. Split method will divide single string into two or more and that's a problem.
How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `Request.Form`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to call them:

```
<input type="text" name="inputNames" />
<input type="text" name="inputNames" />
...
```

And in your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] inputNames)
{
    return View();
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about splitting. You controller action will already receive an array.